# How to run DartVoid Vane application on localhost

Tags: dart, dartvoid, vane

In Vane Roadmap:

> Better support for running Vane on localhost. Right now it's certainly
>   possible to run Vane on localhost, but it's a little bit tricky. On
>   DartVoid we autogenerate a dart based server using the http_server
>   package. And all you need to initialize a Vane class is a standard
>   HttpRequest object. So, this will come soon hopefully. You can find
>   your autogenerated server.dart file at the root of you app if you have
>   a DartVoid app (it's not generated if you use a different framework).

I've created Guestbook sample application and file server.dart was missing.

Is Guestbook sample DartVoid app?

Can I reach generated server.dart file via GitHub?

Is there another way to reach this file?

Please create tags for Vane and DartVoid...

Answer (score 2):

File can be reached from application:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:vane/vane.dart';

String collectionName = "posts";

class GetAllPosts extends Vane {
  Future main() {
   log.info("Guestbook : GetAllPosts");

   new File("server.dart").readAsString().then((String fileContent){
     log.info(fileContent);
   });
  return end;
}
}
```

Content of file will appear in system console in http://manage.dartvoid.com

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR
Vane doesn't need an auto-generated server.dart file anymore, which makes it super easy to use.**

**Long answer**

As the co-founder of [DartVoid](http://www.dartvoid.com) and a co-author of Vane maybe I can give a small update on how we have improved Vane's routing.

We have since the OP's question moved away from auto-generating a server file and instead we use annotations to declare Routes. At startup we parse these routes to build the 'routing table'.

If you're interested in knowing the gritty details and see a couple of examples, I recommend that you head over to the project repository at:
https://github.com/DartVoid/Vane